# jQuery Validate hidden input only if other field has value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form and I am having a problem getting a hidden input only to validate if the password field has been entered.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-4">Password: </label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Password Strength</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="password-meter">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" id="password-meter-progress"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="password_strength" id="password_strength">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirm_password" class="control-label col-sm-4">Confirm Password: </label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do a click on a button like this, it does nothing. I've tried logging out `v.errorList` but don't see anything there

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if (v.form()) {
        $('.frm').hide('fast');
        $('#sf2').show('slow');
    }
});
```

Here is my validate code

```
function isPasswordPresent() {
    return $('#password').val() !== '';
}
var v = $('#onboardingform').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#password",
        },
        password_strength: {
             min: {
                depends: isPasswordPresent,
                param: 60
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        password_strength: {
            min: 'Enter a strong password'
        }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-inline",
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you have included all of your code but if you have, you are targeting a button with the id of button, but there isn't a button with that id. The same goes for the forms inside of the click event.

Comment: That's not the problem.I found the problem is with ignore: [],. If i remove that the form validates fine but my dependent rule no longer works

Comment: That makes no sense.  `ignore: []` simply means to ignore nothing; validate hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Quote [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850290/jquery-validate-hidden-input-only-if-other-field-has-value#comment80649265_46850290):

> *"I found the problem is with `ignore: []`,. If i remove that the form validates fine but my dependent rule no longer works"*

That makes no sense.  `ignore: []` simply means to ignore nothing; validate all fields, including all hidden fields.  So as your title indicates, if you'd like to validate a hidden field, then you must set the `ignore` option accordingly, such as to `[]`.

---

Also, there is no need to write an external function to test whether a field contains a value.  The plugin provides `:filled` and `:blank` selectors for that.

Use `$('#password').is(':filled')` to see if it's filled out, or alternatively, you could use `!$('#password').is(':blank')` to make sure it's not blank.

```
password_strength: {
    min: {
        depends: function(element) {
            return $('#password').is(':filled');
            // return !$('#password').is(':blank');
        },
        param: 60
    }
}
```

**See**:  [jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/)

**Proof-of-concept demo**: [jsfiddle.net/g6hq8o7y/](https://jsfiddle.net/g6hq8o7y/)